# NoMethodError in ImagesController#import / undefined method `import' for Image:Class

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an error while uploading `.csv` file and also as image uploading into my webpage:

> Error NoMethodError in ImagesController#import
> undefined method `import' for Image:Class

Model/image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
   has_one_attached :avatar
     end
def self.import
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
          Image.create! row.to_hash
     end
end
```

controller/images_controller.rb

```
 def import
    Image.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to images_path, notice: "excel import successfully"
  end
```

Comment: Please check the code you have posted. It looks like you declare the `Image` class and then you immediately `end` it after the `has_one_attached` statement

Comment: im using image upload function

Comment: @beniutek this code should raise `syntax error, unexpected \`end'`.

Comment: no, it won't raise a syntax error. He has defined the class and then defined a method  `import` after closing the class definition block. After loading this file method `import` will be defined on the `Object` and can be called without issues. The problem is that he was expecting it to be defined on the `Import` class (which would have been the case if `end` was in the proper place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should remove the `end` from line no. 3 and place it at the end of file i.e., class methods and instance methods should be defined inside a class here
2. As method `import` accepts parameters, define it as `import(arg)`

Below snippet should help you understand better.

```
    class Image < ApplicationRecord
       has_one_attached :avatar
    
       def self.import(file)
           CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
               Image.create! ... # required attributes
           end
       end
    end
```

Comment: thanks , now its working fine , again thank u lot  for supporting me ...